# Garage on the 2nd floor of a 3 story townhome on a hill-slope

Tags: garage, foundation, construction, new-home, slope

I was looking at a 3-story 2000's townhome in a good community built on a hill - The top 2 stories are both open on all sides, with the bottom one under road level and closed off on one side.

```
            ________________________
            |    Living Area       |
            ________________________
Road Level  | Garage     | Bedroom | 
XXXXXXXXXXXX ________________________
XXXXXXXXXXXX| Bedroom    | Bedroom | Backyard|
```

Considering it's a new-ish home, should I be worried about the Garage being on top of a bedroom? We were planning to have our children live in the bottom floor, so that's added a bit to the anxiety. Is this a fairly common scenario in homes on hills?

Comment: What is your anxiety? The car falling through the floor? Not likely.

Comment: As silly as it sounds - Yes :(. Is this a thing I should worry about at all?

Comment: Read the last two words of my comment.

Comment: Assuming that the house was designed this way, don't worry. If an unqualified person changed a living space into a garage, then worry. The latter doesn't seem likely.

Comment: That is the case. Thank you very much for your responses.